# React Hook Scroll to bottom of overflowing div on page load

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to scroll only an overflowing div while keeping the rest of the page at the normal starting position. Right now I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null` error when calling `UseEffect`

Code

```
import React, {Fragment, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

const VideoPlayer = ({...foo...}) => {

   const chatRef = useRef(null)
       const scroll = () => {
           chatRef.current.scrollIntoView();
       }


   useEffect(() => {
           foo_function
           scroll()
       }, [foo_function]);

   }

   return (
   ...other-non-overflowing-div-content...

   <div>
      <div ref={chatRef}>
         <Link to={'/login'}>
           <p className='chat-sign-in'>Sign in to usechat</p>
         </Link>
       </div>
   </div>

   )
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `useRef`. Try a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) instead. You can also pass it as a function with same signature.

```
<div ref={el => el.scrollintoview()}/>
```

Or

```
const cb = el => {
  foo();
  el.scrollintoview();
}

<div ref={cb}/>
```

Comment: This is the solution, I implemented it in a functional component, and it works as expected. The function in the ref is updated as mentioned in the docs. Thx, @zero298

Answer (score 0):

Use `useLayoutEffect` instead `useEffect`

Here is a sandbox for a simple use-case

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-pasteur-44rfz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried that - I still got "Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null"

Comment: Please add an explanation with your answer.